# Div leak parent container max width

Tags: html, css, sass, styles

I need to make a child div leak the parent container max width.
Now, i can only leak parent padding (knowing it).

I need this to wrap all the page on a container and make some sections leak.

Without this, i will need to set the container on every section.

Here is some snippets

[Better snippet on codepen](https://codepen.io/MaxViewUp/pen/KqerOO?editors=1100)

```css
.container {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 30px;
  background: lightblue;
}

.child {
  background: lightcoral;
  height: 200px;
}

.child.cancel-padding {
  margin: 0 -30px;
}

.child.leaked {
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<small>note: see in fullscreen or on codepen</small>
<h1>what i have</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">A element inside a container</div>
</div>

<h1>what i need</h1>
<div class="container-leaked">
  <div class="child leaked">
    a element inside the container, but leaking all view width (100vw)
  </div>
</div>

<h1>what i can do now</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="child cancel-padding">Make the element cancel the parent padding, that's all</div>
</div>

<h1>Why i need</h1>
<p>
  i will wrap all the page in the container, but sometimes i need sections to leak the container with full view width.
</p>
```

Note: on the demo, i've set the child height, but i will not have control of it. it's a dynamic content div, so height is dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using relative positioning. Indeed, you need `position: relative` on your container and your child -leak. Then, to center your child, you use

```
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

This works because your container is centered. So `left: 50%` will move the child left edge to 50% of its parent width from its initial position (which mean the center of its parent). Then, `transform: translateX(-50%)` will move the left edge of your child 50% of its width on the left. You then just need to add `width: 100vw` to make your child full width. Here is the snippet:

```css
.page {
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  max-width: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 30px;
  background: lightblue;
  position: relative;
}

.child-leak {
  height: 200px;
  background: lightcoral;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100vw;
}


html, body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <h1>My title</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="child-leak">
      My full width child
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>Below content</div>
</div>
```

This technique for horizontally center an element works also for vertical centering. This works because a value in % for **top**, **left**, **right** and **bottom** refers to the **first non static parent** width and height. On the other hand, `translate` with a value in % use the element width and height.

Comment: This is great! but in general, i will not have control to the child height. I set a height only to demonstration, but i need something more dynamic. Still, this will help when i have control of the child height.

Comment: I have updated the code, it is now fully dynamic and use a really good technique to center an element.

Comment: Now is working! Thanks for the great idea. I didn't want to use transform because it brings some limitations to the content, but this can be solved. I've added box sizing to the child element (because it's padding, it was overflowing the body). +1

Comment: Hello again, i've created another related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48300255/section-leak-generating-horizontal-scroll

Answer (score 1):

This may be a little bit of a hack, but I've done it before by adding ::before and ::after. Add position: relative to the .child and then add the following css

```
.child.leaked:before{
  content:"";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: -100%;
  background-color: red;
  top: 0;
}

.child.leaked:after{
  content:"";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  right: -100%;
  background-color: red;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Side note, add overflow-x: hidden to the body if you don't have it applied already

Comment: using this works when i have only color blocks leaking, but i still need a way to leak the real child, something that removes the container restriction.

Comment: Hello again, i've created another related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48300255/section-leak-generating-horizontal-scroll

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach you can try:

```css
.container {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 30px;
  background: lightblue;
}

.child {
  background: lightcoral;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400%;
  margin-left: -150%; /* (width of child - 100) / 2 */
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden; /* prevent horizontal scroll bar */
}

* {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">I am outside the parent</div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is a good approach, but the child leaks too much. I need something that  still fits on view width. Can you think on a negative margin math that can do this? (you still knows the container padding and max width, and have the css calc and breakpoints)

Comment: Hello again, i've created another related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48300255/section-leak-generating-horizontal-scroll