# Section Leak generating horizontal scroll

Tags: html, css, overflow, transform

I'm trying to create a way to leak an element from it's parent container.

I'm using `max-width` and `margin: auto` for the container to center.

The child element has `position: relative` and uses `left + translateX transform` to become centered.

The CSS works OK until the page gets scrolling (content height higher than screen height).

This vertical scroll also generates horizontal scrolling.

I was able to hide it using `overflow-x: hidden` but i really want to know **why i'm getting an horizontal scroll?**

Maybe is because the transform? CODE BELOW (see in fullscreen):

```css
.leaked {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translatex(-50%);
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 960px;
  position: relative;
}


/* EXTRA */

.block {
  padding: 20px 0;
  background: darkred;
  color: white;
}

body {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

figcaption {
  text-align: center;
  color: gray;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

.force-scroll {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<article class="container">
  <header>
    <h1>Article title</h1>
    <small>To see in action, use and 1024px wide screen or larger</small>
  </header>
  <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim dolore quaerat quos ex quo laborum officiis maxime molestias cum omnis. Veritatis quas, molestiae nihil soluta inventore provident minus nostrum atque!</p>
  <figure class="leaked">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1920x800" alt="Example figure" width="1920" height="800">
    <figcaption>An example figure</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim dolore quaerat quos ex quo laborum officiis maxime molestias cum omnis. Veritatis quas, molestiae nihil soluta inventore provident minus nostrum atque!</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint quis pariatur totam nostrum explicabo doloremque quaerat! Ipsum odit dolor ut corrupti hic quae provident voluptates saepe commodi, id culpa praesentium?</p>
  <section class="leaked block">
    <div class="container">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut accusantium doloribus aspernatur laboriosam! Voluptatem blanditiis doloremque earum ab alias, modi repudiandae eveniet autem fugiat facilis ducimus? Veniam laboriosam nobis ab!
      </p>
    </div>

  </section>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque voluptates voluptas eveniet suscipit fugiat. Quidem nesciunt ducimus veritatis, sed repudiandae perferendis nam fugiat! Laborum minus consequatur hic. Ut, dolorum facilis.</p>
  <div class="force-scroll">This is only to force an scroll</div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths)

The **viewport-percentage lengths** are relative to the size of the initial containing block. When the height or width of the initial containing block is changed, they have scaled accordingly.

> However, when the value of overflow on the root element is auto, any
>   scrollbars are assumed not to exist.

So there is no way to without js to get width without scrollbars :(

Comment: Thanks, the answer is right, i've tested it with an pen. Can be solved using an wrapper with overflow-x: hidden https://codepen.io/MaxViewUp/pen/baOOGQ

Comment: I can't award this bounty now, but you will probably get it. If you have suggestions to fix this problem, they will be welcome.

Comment: Overflow hidden almost always is a bad idea because if you'll have something like the bootstrap grid, or some not full-width container, your 'full-width element' max width will be same as in your container: 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xpBgYo

Comment: Yes i know, but using only overflow-x on an top parent container (that follow the window width) only hides elements that overflow the window, an 101vw element for example.

Comment: In this case, I think the much better solution is to set max-width with js. 
For most cases simple script should do the job:
https://codepen.io/Xopoc/pen/wpRXVe

For more complex cases, as an SPA or dynamic content load, you should detect body size change, or create a handler for content change.

Comment: Yes i've used that before, but i think is not good practice to depend on JS to add CSS, just when is really not possible (or compatible with all browsers).

Answer (score 1):

It's the width on .leaked. I changed the width from `100vw` to `100%` and the image reduces in size so it now fits in the container.

```
.leaked {
    width: 100%;
    //other styles
}
```

But if you do want the leaked content to go full width you need to change your html structure so .leaked sections are not inside the container, that way it will go full width:

```
<article class="container">
  <header>
    <h1>Article title</h1>
    <small>To see in action, use and 1024px wide screen or larger</small>
  </header>
  <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim dolore quaerat quos ex quo laborum officiis maxime molestias cum omnis. Veritatis quas, molestiae nihil soluta inventore provident minus nostrum atque!</p>
  </article>
  <figure class="leaked">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1920x800" alt="Example figure" width="1920" height="800">
    <figcaption>An example figure</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <article class="container">
  <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim dolore quaerat quos ex quo laborum officiis maxime molestias cum omnis. Veritatis quas, molestiae nihil soluta inventore provident minus nostrum atque!</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint quis pariatur totam nostrum explicabo doloremque quaerat! Ipsum odit dolor ut corrupti hic quae provident voluptates saepe commodi, id culpa praesentium?</p>
  </article>
  <section class="leaked block">
    <div class="container">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut accusantium doloribus aspernatur laboriosam! Voluptatem blanditiis doloremque earum ab alias, modi repudiandae eveniet autem fugiat facilis ducimus? Veniam laboriosam nobis ab!
      </p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <article class="container">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque voluptates voluptas eveniet suscipit fugiat. Quidem nesciunt ducimus veritatis, sed repudiandae perferendis nam fugiat! Laborum minus consequatur hic. Ut, dolorum facilis.</p>
  <div class="force-scroll">This is only to force an scroll</div>
</article>
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but i'm trying to archive an way to leak elements inside an container without changing the HTML structure. What i'm trying to understand is why an horizontal scroll is generated. As i said on the question, i solve the problem setting `overflow-x: hidden`

Comment: Are you not able to change the html structure? That would be the best way to solve this issue. `overflow-x: hidden` works too to mask the issue. The scroll is just because the leaked elements are wider than the viewport. try adding `margin-left: -10px;` to your .leaked class (tried it on your snippet and it worked)

Comment: About the HTML: I'm developing an reusable component that may or may be not on an container. That's why i wan't to make it this way (try to look at medium artcles that have full images and contained article). This is an style issue so changing the HTML to make the style work isn't an good solution on my case. And about the `margin-left`, this only work for you because your browser scrollbar has 10px wide. Each browser has it's own scrollbar width.